# How to update mysql table column based on other column value in same row

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table like this.

```
table_categories - scid, scname, scimage
```

I want to update scimage field of each row to  "/images/subcategories/"scid".png"

```
update table_categories set scimage = "/images/subcategories/" + <What should i write here, so it take scid value> + ".png"
```

Comment: Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat): `set scimage = CONCAT("/images/subcategories/", scid, ".png")`

Comment: If `scid` is not `varchar` then you have to `CAST` it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your column name like:

```
update table_categories set scimage = "/images/subcategories/" + scid + ".png"
```

If your column type is not varchar you must [convert your datatype at the first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html).